# Does java library update when changing file in path?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have created a library to use some utilities I need in multiple projects. So lets say I'm building a new version of the library and overwrite the old one, do my other project automatically update the library to the newer version when I reload my project? (Or when I build it)

Comment: How do those other project retrieve that library? Are you manually copying new one and replacing old versions? If so, then yes, however you run your java project, it'll of course use new version (since you overwrote it). You need to provide more details and be more precise in describing the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be referencing external libraries by relative path unless you have a good reason for it, exactly for reasons like these. Ideally you want to use a build automation tool which will handle this, for example Maven, Gradle or Ant, so that the dependencies are included on compile and are a part of your JAR or whatever you are building your project into.

https://www.baeldung.com/ant-maven-gradle